# Checking backpropagation gradients

Tags: tensorflow, backpropagation

I'm trying to adapt a reinforcement learning script that's coded in pure python into tensorflow.

I designed it and when I started sampling through it I got exactly the same values in forward propagation (for the first samples), but then I backpropagate and gradient values are not the same (not even close).

I'm thinking that it has to do with backprop through the RELU non-linearity but then again I'm not entirely sure.

What's the easiest way to see step by step backpropagation of a network architecture?

Answer (score 6):

One way is to print the values of the backpropagation gradients:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer() 
variables = tf.trainable_variables()
gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(cost, variables)
```

You then can inspect the values of the computed gradients by passing them to the `sess.run` function